# ETIMEDOUT error in Next.Js API endpoint GET request using Axios in Development Env and not Production

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios, linkedin-api, next.js13

So, I'm trying to fetch linkedin user details. I've written an API endpoint for this.
Here's how I'm doing:

1. From my client side, I call the API:

```js
const subId = await axios.get(
   `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL}/auth/linkedin-access/fetch/sub-id?access_token=${user?.linkedin_access_token}`
);
```

2. This is my `/auth/linkedin-access/fetch/sub-id/route.ts`:

```js
import { fetchSubId } from "@/utils/linkedin-api-handlers/fetch-sub-id";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
 try {
   const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
   const access_token = searchParams.get("access_token");

   if (!access_token) {
     return NextResponse.json(
       {
         path: "/auth/linkedin-access/fetch/sub-id/route",
         error: "no access token",
       },
       { status: 401, statusText: "access_token not present" }
     );
   }

   const response = await fetchSubId(access_token);  // possibly here lies the problem

   return NextResponse.json({ sub: response });
 } catch (e) {
   return NextResponse.json(
     {
       path: "/auth/linkedin-access/fetch/sub-id/route",
       error: e,
     },
     { status: 500 }
   );
 }
}
```

3. This is my function for the GET request:

```js
export async function fetchSubId(accessToken: string): Promise<string> {
 const req = axios.create({
   headers: {
     Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
     Connection: "keep-alive",
   },
 });

 const response = await req.get("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo");

 return response.data.sub;
}
```

Response:

```json
{
    "path": "/auth/linkedin-access/fetch/sub-id/route",
    "error": {
        "message": "",
        "name": "AggregateError",
        "stack": "AggregateError\n    at AxiosError.from (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/axios/lib/core/AxiosError.js:85:16)\n    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:513:81)\n    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:524:35)\n    at eventHandlers.<computed> (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/follow-redirects/index.js:21:28)\n    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:512:28)\n    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:512:28)\n    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)\n    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)",
        "config": {
            "transitional": {
                "silentJSONParsing": true,
                "forcedJSONParsing": true,
                "clarifyTimeoutError": false
            },
            "adapter": [
                "xhr",
                "http"
            ],
            "transformRequest": [
                null
            ],
            "transformResponse": [
                null
            ],
            "timeout": 60000,
            "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
            "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
            "maxContentLength": -1,
            "maxBodyLength": -1,
            "env": {},
            "headers": {
                "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                "Authorization": "Bearer XXXXX",
                "Connection": "keep-alive",
                "User-Agent": "axios/1.4.0",
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br"
            },
            "method": "get",
            "url": "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo"
        },
        "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
        "status": null
    }
}
```